# How to create a proxy extension with click enabled in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I need to create a proxy extension with click enabled. The first thing the extesion would not start. It gives error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

I just follow documentation and several thread to test first. I checked already theres nothing typo close syntax like bracket, curly bracket and semi-colon.

Manifest

```
{
"name": "Secure Proxy",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "Secure Proxy",
"permissions": [
    "proxy"
],
"background": {
    "scripts":["js/background.js"]
    },
"browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
        "16": "images/logo16.png",
        "32": "images/logo32.png",
        "48": "images/logo48.png",
        "128": "images/logo128.png"
    }
},
"icons": {
    "16": "images/logo16.png",
    "32": "images/logo32.png",
    "48": "images/logo48.png",
    "128": "images/logo128.png"
  },
"manifest_version": 2
```

}

Script

```
    var unblock = document.getElementById('unblock');

var config = {
  mode: "fixed_servers",
  rules: {
    singleProxy: {
      scheme: "http",
      host: "103.66.47.126",
      port: 8080
    }
  }
};

unblock.addEventListener('click', function(){

  chrome.proxy.settings.set(
  {value: config, scope: 'regular'},
  function() {});

}, false);
```

popup

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
      <button id="unblock">Unblock</button>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to come from the code you're showing. You can either complete or comprise a minimal reproducible example.